# Integrating over a matrix of points

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, calculus

I have a matrix of points F(x,y) = z, but I have no expression for F(x,y). 
x is from [0-2pi] and y is from [0-pi]. For each pair of "coordinates", I have a value of z.

I would like to perform a double integration from 0-2pi and 0-pi of F. Can I do this computationally (MatLab) without having an analytical expression?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, because the (_x_,_y_) grid is not uniform in the linked question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the (*x*,*y*) grid is uniform, you can approximate the integral by a 2D-[Riemman sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) as follows:

```
result = sum(z(:))*delta_x*delta_y;
```

where `delta_x`, `delta_y` are the grid spacings in the *x* and *y* directions. In your case these can be computed as

```
delta_x = 2*pi/numel(x); %// or 2*pi/(numel(x)-1)
delta_y = pi/numel(x); %// or pi/(numel(x)-1)
```

---

A perhaps more intuitive interpretation: compute the mean value of the function and multiply by the area of the (*x*,*y*) domain:

```
result = sum(z(:))/(numel(x)*numel(y)) * 2*pi^2; %// or replace numel(x)*numel(y) 
                                                 %// by numel(z)
```